# Given two i.i.d uniform random variables $X$ and $Y$, find the joint distribution of $U = X + Y$ and $V = X/(X+Y)$.

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution, jacobian

The question asks you to solve this using the jacobian method. From the question, we get that:
$X = VU$ and $Y = U(V-1)$ and so the jacobian yields: $|J| = |U|$.

So we get: $f_{UV}(u,v) =|J| \cdot f_{XY}(uv,u(v-1))$. Since X and Y are i.i.d, $f_{XY}(x,y) = 1/4$, if x $\in (0,2)$ and y $\in (0,2)$.

So the final result is: $f_{UV}(u,v) =|u|/4$ if $0<uv<2$ and $0<u(v-1)<2$.

But both regions $0<uv<2$ and $0<u(v-1)<2$ described by this joint distribution have infinite area, so is the final joint distribution valid? Or maybe the jacobian method cannot be applied in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all there is a mistake. $Y = U(1-V)$ and not $U(V-1)$.

Now, $f_{UV}(u,v) = u \cdot f_{XY}(uv,u(1-v))$. I removed the absolute value as $u$ cannot be negative. You will see why as you go through the answer.

As you said, $0 \lt uv \lt 2$ and $0 \lt u (1-v) \lt 2$

From $0 \lt uv \lt 2$, observe that $u$ and $v$ must have the same sign.

From $0 \lt u(1-v) \lt 2$, $v$ cannot be greater thant $1$ as $u$ and $v$ canno]t have different signs.

Also $u$ and $v$ cannot be negative as for $u, v \lt 0$, $u(1-v) \lt 0$

Now for $0 \lt u \lt 2$ and $0 \lt v \lt 1$, there are no restrictions and any values of $u, v$ work.

Also note intersection of $uv = u (1-v) \implies v = \frac{1}{2}, u = 4$

So for $2 \lt u \lt 4$, we have

$\frac{u-2}{u} \lt v \lt \frac{2}{u}$ and $v$ is always less than $1$

For $u \gt 4$, we get contradiction in value of $v$ from both equations.

So support of the distribution is given by,

$$0 \lt v \lt 1, 0 \lt u \lt 2$$
$$\frac{u-2}{u} \lt v \lt \frac{2}{u}, 2 \lt u \lt 4$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That silly mistake at the beginning was really the biggest problem, thank you for your time :)

Comment: *Alternatively* ensuring that $UV\in(0,2)$ while $U(1-V)\in(0,2)$ also means that is $V\in(0,1)$ and $U\in(0,\min\{2/V,2/(1-V)\})$, so partitioning at $V=1/2$ gives a support of :$$({0<v<1/2~\&~0<u<2/(1-v)})\text{ or }({1/2\leqslant v<1~\&~0<u<2/v}) $$